# Get .NET jit-compiler logs

Tags: .net, compilation, jit

I'd love to find out which methods in which order are JIT compiled.

I know there is a profiler API that allows that, but i'll have to write profiler in C++ for that.
Also there is a feature called ProfileOptimization that create JIT profile for faster background JITting in future. It creates some binary file. Maybe there is a possibility to get method names from it if i have .exe/.pdb ?

I used perfmon to get count of JITted methods, but count is not enough to start my nano optimization war

Thanks!

Comment: It is not the only "but".  Suppose you get the C++ code going, as is necessary, and you learn about the jitting order, what are you going to do to actually *change* it?  Why do you expect the program to work better?  Pretty high odds that you'll make it worse.  You cannot beat background jitting anyway.  Or Ngen.exe, the most obvious way to not jit at all.

Comment: I can change code and measure. If it doesn't work better - i'll leave code as is :) That is why i'm sure it will work better. 
NGEN/PGO is not an option in my case. I want to play with jitting a bit, but i need logs. If they contain JIT time of specific method- it would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PerfView](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/10/09/improving-your-apps-performance-with-perfview/) to get the order in which functions are being JIT-compiled. To be more specific, you can use the JIT Stats which you can generate and access as described in the section "Background JIT in Action" of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt683795) article.

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what i needed.

Comment: @Grigory Please don't forget to mark the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: Yes, Sir! Done! :)